# Visualize start and end of activities as geom_segments relative to base line activity

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table such as this:

```
df <- structure(list(Line = c("130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", 
                              "136", "137", "139", "140", "141"), 
                     Actor = c("R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "R", "B", "B", "M", "M", "M"), 
                     Act_cat = c("ver", "SpeechRec", "ges", "ges", "gaze", "ges", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze", "gaze"), 
                     Activity = c("dort drüben könnt ihr sehen wer damals auf der sparrenburg gewohnt hat",
                                  "schwert", "D-onset", "D-peak", "~", "D-retract", "@tum", "~", "~", "@tum", "~"),
                     Starttime_ms = c(48825, 48865, 49220, 50080, 50730, 50900, 
                                      51009, 51191, 51486, 51809, 52251), 
                     Endtime_ms = c(53035, 49865, 50080, 50900, 51009, 52220, 51191, 51270, 51808, 52250, 
                                                                                         52332), 
                     Duration = c(4210, 1000, 860, 820, 279, 1320, 182, 79, 322, 441, 81)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -11L), 
                groups = structure(list(File = "VP_4_004", .rows = structure(list(1:11), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of","vctrs_vctr", "list"))), 
                                   row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

I want to visualize how the `Activity`s *after* the first temporally relate to that first `Activity`, namely "dort drüben könnt ihr sehen wer damals auf der sparrenburg gewohnt hat". The kind of visualization I have in mind would involve the use of `geom_segment`s for each `Activity`, their positions and end points would be determined by their `Starttime_ms` and, respectively, `Endtime_ms` values and *could* look roughly like this:

[image]

How can this be obtained? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick first go. You could potentially use `geom_tile`, `geom_rect`, or `geom_segment` here, depending on how you want to specify the position/size. I think `geom_tile` might be simplest, but its x/y is based on the centerpoint.

```
ggplot(df, aes( y = Act_cat)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = Starttime_ms + Duration/2, width = Duration,  height = 0.8, fill = Actor), color = "white") +
  geom_text(aes(x = Starttime_ms, label = stringr::str_wrap(Activity, 30)), hjust = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: That's already a good starting point! How can I center the text? And why is the reference `Activity` broken into three lines?

Comment: `aes(x = Starttime_ms + Duration/2)...., hjust = 0.5` should do it

Comment: How can the text be rotated when there's not enough horizonatl space?

Comment: I added `stringr::str_wrap` on the presumption that some text might get too long to fit in a single line. You might look at the ggtext package for some more options for fitting text, like ggtext::geom_textbox()

Comment: To rotate, I'd suggest adding a column in your data, like `rot = c(0,0,0,0,90)` and then use `geom_text(aes(..... angle = rot))` so that you can control which labels get rotated. If you want to automate further you could even have that `rot` column depend on the length of the label and/or the size the of the bar. I don't know anything built-in though.

Comment: Hi again @Jon Spring. `geom_text(aes(x = Starttime_ms, label = Activity), hjust = -0.5)` only works for the first `Activity` as far as centering is concerned; the other `Activity`s are moved to the right but not centered. Any help?

Comment: `aes(x = Starttime_ms + Duration/2, label = Activity)...., hjust = 0.5` should do it

Comment: No, `hjust = 0.5` pulls the text to the left instead of centering it in the tiles.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242121/discussion-between-jon-spring-and-chris-ruehlemann).